# Counting hyphenated and quoted words in a string

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to write a program which when given an input, will spit out how many words are hyphenated, and how many are in quotes. A few sample inputs and outputs are as follows:

Enter sentence:

Joe likes quasi­-sci­-fi books like "Left Hand of Darkness" and 
"Frankenstein"

Words with hyphens:

1

Words in quotes

5

Enter sentence:

"jack is happy"

Words with hyphens:

0

Words in quotes :

3

Enter sentence:

this is a "hyphenated-­word" in quotes

Words with hyphens:

1

Words in quotes :

1

So far I have been unable to get this to work, and am not quite sure if my approach is the correct one.  Here is what I have written so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string inistr, substr, quotestr;
    getline(cin, inistr);
    int hyphen=0, firstQuote, quote=0, firstHyphen;

while(inistr.length() > 0){
    if(inistr.find_first_of('"') == string::npos && inistr.find_first_of('-') == string::npos){
        inistr = "";

    }
    else if((inistr.find_first_of('"') != string::npos && inistr.find_first_of('-') == string::npos) || (inistr.find_first_of('"') != string::npos && (inistr.find_first_of('-')>inistr.find_first_of('"')))){
        firstQuote = inistr.find("\""); 

        substr = inistr.substr(inistr.find_first_of("\""), inistr.find("\"",firstQuote +  1)+1);
        inistr = inistr.substr(inistr.find("\"",firstQuote+1)+1);

        if(substr.find_first_of("-") != string::npos){
            hyphen++;
            quote++;
        }
        if(substr.find(' ') == string::npos && substr.find("-") == string::npos){
            quote = 1;
        }
        else if(substr.find(' ') != string::npos){
            quote = 1;
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < substr.length(); i++){
                if(substr.at(i) == ' '){
                    quote++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if((inistr.find_first_of('-') != string::npos && inistr.find_first_of('"') == string::npos) || (inistr.find_first_of('-') != string::npos && (inistr.find_first_of('"')>inistr.find_first_of('-')))){
    firstHyphen = inistr.find_first_of('-');
    substr = inistr.substr(firstHyphen, inistr.find(' ', firstHyphen + 1));
    inistr = inistr.substr(inistr.find(substr) + substr.length(), ' ');
    hyphen++;
    }
}

    cout << "Words with hyphens:" << hyphen << endl;
    cout << "Words in quotes:" << quote << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output I get when putting the first example in.

Joe likes quasi-sci-fi books like "Left Hand of Darkness" and "Frankenstein"

Words with hyphens:1

Words in quotes:3

Comment: First, use `std::istringstream` along with `operator >>`.  That would shorten the code you wrote by a ton.

Comment: [Start here](http://ideone.com/ryiCiv).  First make sure you get each word efficiently and easily.  Your current code is very convoluted in just that one aspect.  Once you have each word, then add logic to figure out if the word has hyphens or starts / ends with quotes, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That looks like it works great, but how would somebody do that in c++11?

Comment: That *is* C++11 code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if it is not compiling on my machine does that mean I am running C++ 98?  I'm not quite sure how to check that.  I am running Geany for Ubuntu version 1.29.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Nevermind, I figured it out. Thank you.